# how to use contextBridge in other files when it is used in preload.js in electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I am using context bridge and I used this format in preload.js

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', {
    hello: ()=>ipcRenderer.send('hi-there'),
});
```

How do i call this function 'hello()' in other files where i want the string 'hi-there' to be printed.

Comment: window.api.hello()?

Answer (score 1):

You've done the preload.js side of the work, to call this in your render.js files, do this.

```
window.api.hello()
```

exposeInMainWorld() will insert the functions in the window object of the side of teh application.